# Linking inside <li> children not working properly with jquery

Tags: jquery, list, linker, menu, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu with this HTML:

```
<ul id="dropdownmenu" class="dropdown maintopmenu">

<li class="topmenu" link="link0.htm">SELL
    <ul>
        <li link="link1.htm"><span class="menulink">APPLY TO SELL</span>/li>
        <li link="link2.htm"><span class="menulink">FEE/FEATURES</span></li>
        <li link="link3"><span class="menulink">FAQ</span></li>
        <li link="mycart.php?4"><span class="menulink">IMAGE GUIDELINE</span></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Then I have this jquery function which is supposed to go to the page link=whatever on click. What this is doing though, is always going to the first li link (the main parent).
My guess is it is ignoring the whole block inside of that li.

```
$(function() {
    $('li[link]').click(function() {
    document.location.href=($(this).attr('link'));
});
});
```

I need this to work with all levels of submenus.

Comment: Couldn't you just use an anchor tag?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Humor me for a second here - why aren't you using anchor tags inside the list items?  You're reinventing the wheel a little here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because the event is bubbling up to the ancestor `<li>` and firing its handler.

You need to stop propagation of the event using the [`event.stopPropagation()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) method or `return false;`.

```
$('li[link]').click(function( event ) {
    document.location.href = ($(this).attr('link'));
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
          $('li').click(function(e) {
          var $var = $(this).attr("link");
              alert($var);
              e.stopPropagation();
          //document.location.href=($(this).attr('link'));
         } );
    });
```

use e.stopPropagation();

hope this helps

Comment: it was just the matter of time :) patrick dw answered the question first

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not using bizarre, and invalid, attributes for your html and, if that's unavoidable, use jQuery to create traditional mark-up, for example:

```
$('li').each(
    function(){
        var linkTo = $(this).attr('link');
        $(this).find('span').wrap('<a href="' + linkTo + '"></a>');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/CCs54/).

But I'd strongly suggest using the `a` element instead of the JavaScript malarkey, especially since the JS/jQuery doesn't degrade well in the absence of JS.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, put a return false at end of func.

```
$(function() {
    $('li[link]').click(function() {
        document.location.href=($(this).attr('link'));
        return false;
    });
});
```

Its works perfectly!